# Getting rails development logs with Apple Web Sharing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, passenger, tail

I'm using Passenger Pref Pane + Apple native web sharing to host my Rails 3 app in development.  Is there any way that I can tail the rails logs using this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rails logs should always be in `<app>/logs/<environment, usually production>.log`, unless I'm missing something about your setup.  The environment you supply to passenger in the passenger apache config file (the PrefPane is just a UI on top of this) will determine the application's environment.  So if your environment is production and your app directory is `~/projects/my_app` your log file should be in `~/projects/my_app/logs/production.log`

Comment: Thanks — don't know what I was thinking.